# SQL Server : how to insert using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server table using a variable. I tried

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(50) = 'ToolList',
        @val NVARCHAR(50) = 'test'

EXEC ('INSERT INTO ' + @table + 'SELECT ' + @val)
```

and

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO ' + @table + '([col1]) VALUES(' + @val +')'
```

but still get an error that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'test'.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try saving `@val nvarchar(50) = ' test '` give space before and after `test`

Comment: Basic debugging : print or select the string after building it but before you execute it. You'll see you didn't quote your VARCHAR values. Also, look into SP_EXECUTESQL which allows typed parameters for dynamic sql, then you don't need to quote it, and won't be vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed a space before `SELECT` and the `@val` should enclosed in single quote

```
DECLARE @table nvarchar(50) = 'ToolList',
    @val nvarchar(50) = 'test'


EXEC ( 'INSERT INTO ' + @table + ' SELECT ''' + @val + '''')
```

when you use `Dynamic SQL`, it is easier to form the query in a variable so that you can print out , inspect the value before execution

```
select @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table + ' SELECT ''' + @val + ''''
print  @sql
exec  (@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `sp_executesql` that allows for statements to be parameterized, to avoid the risk of SQL injection.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(1000),
    @table NVARCHAR(50) = 'ToolList'

SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table + ' SELECT @val'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@val nvarchar(50)', @val = 'test'
```

[sp-executesql-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Comment: This is absolutely the correct way to go. It protects from attacks, it protects from mistakes, deals with quoting and allows execution plan reuse. The other answers work, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **`CHAR(39)`** instead of adding single quotes every time for better readability. And also, you have not added a space after the variable which contains the table name.

**Query**

```
declare @table nvarchar(50) = 'ToolList',
        @val nvarchar(50) = 'test2';

 declare @sql as varchar(max) = 'insert into ' + @table 
                             + ' select ' + char(39) +  @val + char(39);
exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 singlequotes before the @val field as it is a string and all strings needs to be encapsulated in single quotes.
You can print the dynamic string using PRINT command check what the final string you are going to execute.

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(50) = 'ToolList'
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(50) = 'test'
DECLARE @DSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @DSQL = @DSQL + ' INSERT INTO [' + @table + ']' + ' 
 SELECT ' + '''' + @val + ''''

--PRINT @DSQL
EXEC(@DSQL)
```